# Working on 2 computers - git clone - only differences

Tags: git, github

I work on 2 computers. Whenever I finish work on one i push this for github.
And when it ends up working elsewhere on the other computer i clone my repository from github. And so in the loop.
It is good practice ?
Is it possible to download only differences instead all project file ?

Comment: You do `git pull` to update the code. You need to clone it only once per computer.

Comment: after git pull system returns Already up-to-date - But nothing happens, I have old files

Comment: Please give a complete step-by-step example of what you do that gives this message.

Comment: git fetch next - git pull

Comment: That is still not enough information. Start with "computer 1". What do you do on this machine? Then when you go to "computer 2", what do you do? Please edit your question with a very detailed description.

Comment: computer 1: git add . - git commit -am "something" -git push || computer 2: git fetch - git pull

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to download only differences instead all project file ?

Yes, this is what `git fetch` and `git pull` are for.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `git pull` on the computer on which you start working. It will pull only the changes from GitHub which are not there on the current machine.

Comment: i see only "Already up-to-date." in console, but i still have old files

Comment: Have you pushed changes from the other computer? Do a 'git log' to check the last commit. Also check of that commit is actually the last commit on GitHub too.

Comment: i have this same commit actually like in GitHub, but i have different  content file, In addition i dont have all file projects like github

Comment: Have you committed and pushed your code correctly from your other machine (A)? You can do a `git status` on your other machine(A) to know of there are any un committed files. If there are do `git add .` and then `git commit -am "<commit message>"`. Then do a `git push`, and then `git pull` on your current machine(B).

Answer (score 0):

In both repos you have GitHub repo as remote. You can check it with `git remote -v`, you should look something like:

```
origin  git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git (push)
```

So you can just do `pull` (will change files in the repo) or `fetch` (won't change files in the repo, only `.git` internals).